# How to select the sum of the increments of a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with GSP locations. I'd like to get the sum of the altitude gain.

```
id  altitude
1   0
2   20            -> gained 20
3   10            -> gained 0
4   50            -> gained 40
```

This example should output 60 (20 + 40).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(altitude) over (order by id) < altitude
             then altitude - lag(altitude) over (order by id)
             else 0
        end) as altitude_gain
from t
```

In many databases, this could be simplified to:

```
select t.*,
       greatest(altitude - lag(altitude) over (order by id), 0) as altitude_gain
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub query

```
Select sum(gained) from 
( select a.id, 
Case when a.altitude - coalesce(b.altitude,0) < 0 
Then 0 else a.altitude - b.altitude end as gained
From tbl a left join tbl b on a.id - 1 = b.id) a
```